# Mqttnet managedMqttClient processed vs received Application message

Tags: c#, mqtt, mqttnet

I recently tried implementing a mqttclient in c# using the mqttnet package.
I realized, that there are three events which can be invoked by the library:

```
ApplicationMessageProcessedAsync
ApplicationMessageReceivedAsync
ApplicationMessageSkippedAsync
```

While the last two are rather self-explanatory, I struggle to understand in what regard the ApplicationMessage is processed after its reception. Hence the question: why does `ApplicationMessageProcessedAsync` exist. Also, under what circumstances might the client decide to skip an ApplicationMessage und could this also be related to the processing of a message?

I would be happy for any help, as documentation in the MqttNet package is rather non-existent.

thanks J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You confuse receiving and sending here. While `ApplicationMessageReceivedAsync` is called when a message is received from the broker, the other two relate to publishing messages.

The MqttNet ManagedClient internally has a queue, from which it actually publishes messages. If you call `EnqueueAsync(message)`, but your queue is allready full, the `ApplicationMessageSkippedAsync` event gets called, to tell you about the queue overflow. The message is then not sent.

On the other hand `ApplicationMessageProcessedAsync` is called when a message is published. Depending on QoS level, this is called at slightly different times. This event is also called, when publishing a message fails. In that case it contains the exception for more information.

Comment: thanks that makes it very clear. do you still know by any chance where you got this information?

Comment: I just looked at the source code : https://github.com/dotnet/MQTTnet/blob/master/Source/MQTTnet.Extensions.ManagedClient/ManagedMqttClient.cs